# How do I configure mitmproxy YAML to automatically change a response status code?

Tags: mitmproxy

I know how to intercept a request and modify the response code as it comes in.

I have also had some success with setting up the configuration file to automatically replace headers and the response body.

I have **NOT** been able to find a way to set up the configuration file to automatically replace the *status code* for a given flow.

Is there a way to do this without having to manually intercept?

Comment: As far as I know Mitmproxy is designed to perform such changes by implementing a small Python add-on that allows you to perform any replacement action you want on request/response header and body: https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/addons-examples/

Comment: Thanks @Robert, but I'm specifically targeting a configuration approach as I want to make updating these configurations achievable for non-programmer folks.

Comment: Then may be a different proxy would be more suitable to you. Or you can write a mitmproxy add-on that reads a configuration file where all the replacements are specified.